# how to print random line with variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a variable myline in which I am storing a line with break now I want to print 2 random line can any one suggest how to do that.

```
 import random
 myline="This is line 1 \nThis is line 2 \nThis is line 3 \nThis is line 4 \nThis is line 5  "


lines = myline.readlines()
print (random.sample(lines, 2))
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `splitlines` instead of `readlines`:

```
import random
myline="This is line 1 \nThis is line 2 \nThis is line 3 \nThis is line 4 \nThis is line 5  "


lines = myline.splitlines()
print(random.sample(lines, 2))

# ['This is line 4 ', 'This is line 1 ']
```

`readlines` returns a list of lines from a file. Here, you have a string that you want to split.

If you want to print the lines separated by newlines, just `join` the list of lines with newlines:

```
print('\n'.join(random.sample(lines, 2)))
```

Comment: ['This is line 4 ', 'This is line 1 '] its print like this but I want to print like This is line 4  This is line 1 in next line

Comment: Since I can't post answers anymore, I suggest you to use `random.choice()`, and use a loop to print the number of sentences you want.

Comment: @IMCoins Using `random.choice` repeatedly is different, as it could choose the same line many times, while `sample` garantees each to appear at most once.

Comment: I didn't know this, and I thank you for the information. -- though here it's just a preference I believe. We don't have this kind of information. It must be a home assignment and `random.sample()` won't return anything if the number of random sentences asked is superior to the length of the iterable passed. I would stick with `random.choice()` for safety. :P